# When will the next major update be?

Tags: general-utilities

It's been two years since the release of Mathematica 11, and though 4K has become quite popular now, Mathematica does not support such high DPI. This, along with many bugs found, would probably be fixed in the next major update. So when will it be? And what new features would be added in this upcoming version?

Comment: Have you asked WRI Support or at community.wolfram.com?

Comment: I would close this right away since I believe no one is allowed to say anything and would get into trouble by doing so. However, there were some instances where WRI veterans like TheFultz gave some small inofficial information that wasn't public. If this gets closed, don't be sad. It's just not the right place to ask this question.

Comment: Other questions of this style have been closed before [88880](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/88880/10397).

Comment: There's no date yet for the next release. 
We've been trying to make the "minor" releases more substantial recently. For version 11 they've included some major new functionality and bug fixes. 
Usually, we give sneak peaks at the Wolfram Tech Conference.

Comment: @Searke Nothing against incremental development, and version numbers are just a... heh, somebody would say "a social construct." I'd wish this approach brings more speedy resolutions to minor bugs, too, because sometimes I feel that life is too short for them. I mean, there are bugs whose resolution I've waited substantial portion of my lifetime!

Comment: @kirma The balance of attention to bugfixes versus new features can vary from area to area. No one agrees exactly on what the balance should be, but the minor versions have included a large number of bug fixes. Additionally, there's a large number of bug fixes between versions with paclet updates and fixes to Wolfram|Alpha itself. It can be hard for the developers to gauge how serious a bug really is. So it's always helpful to file bug reports with Wolfram Tech Support.